# Json/Nodejs: How do I get specific data from a JSON file

Tags: node.js, json

I am trying to develop a discord bot with nodejs. My question is how do I get a specific data out of a JSON file (for instance, from [this json](https://hastebin.com/ovamosabay.json). I want to only specify a single uuid like "59d4c622c7cc459a98c2e947054e2b11" and get the data.

Comment: Could you share your approach so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already parsed the JSON into an actual Javascript object named `data` and given the way the data is currently organized, you would have to search the `data.guild.members` array to find the object that had the desired `uuid` property value.

```
function findDataForUuid(uuid) {
     for (let obj of data.guild.members) {
        if (obj.uuid === uuid) {
            return obj;
        }
     }
     // no match found
     return null;
}


let item = findDataForUuid("59d4c622c7cc459a98c2e947054e2b11");
if (item) {
    console.log(item);    // will show all the properties of the member object
}
```

---

Or, using `.find()` on the array:

```
function findDataForUuid(uuid) {
     return data.guild.members.find(item => {
         return item.uuid === uuid;
     });
}
```

Comment: can i get the rank and other data out of it then?

Comment: @Myzumi - Yes, this returns the whole object containing that uuid so you can read the `.rank`, `.joined`, `.questParticipation`, `expHistory` properties on the returned object.

Comment: @Myzumi - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The simple soln you can use filter. Best is use reduce.

```js
const data = {
  guild: {
    _id: "5b2906070cf29ddccd0f203c",
    name: "Dulcet",
    coins: 122010,
    coinsEver: 232010,
    created: 1529415175560,
    members: [
      {
        uuid: "59d4c622c7cc459a98c2e947054e2b11",
        rank: "MEMBER",
        joined: 1529683128302,
        questParticipation: 39,
        expHistory: {
          "2020-02-16": 0,
          "2020-02-15": 0,
          "2020-02-14": 0,
          "2020-02-13": 0,
          "2020-02-12": 0,
          "2020-02-11": 0,
          "2020-02-10": 0
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

const members = data.guild.members.filter(
  member => member.uuid == "59d4c622c7cc459a98c2e947054e2b11"
);

const firstMember = members[0]
console.log(firstMember)
```